# Markov Chain Definition Question

Tags: statistics, markov-chains

This is a very basic question about Markov chains, but I am desperately lost.  We are given the following definition of a Markov chain:

$P(X_{n+1}\in A | X_1 = x_1, ..., X_n=x_n) = P(X_{n+1} \in A |X_n = x_n)$

for all measurable sets $A$.

Show that $P(X_{n+1}\in A | X_1 = x_1, ..., X_{n-k}=x_{n-k}) = P(X_{n+1}\in A | X_{n-k}=x_{n-k})$ for all $k \ge 1$.

I started by trying to condition on $X_n$ and proceed from there (assuming the $X_i$ all have densities $f$), but I've gotten nowhere:

$$P(X_{n+1}\in A | X_1 = x_1, ..., X_{n-k}=x_{n-k})$$

$$ = \int P(X_{n+1}\in A, X_n = x_n | X_1 = x_1, ..., X_{n-k}=x_{n-k})f(x_n)dx_n$$

$$ = \int P(X_{n+1}\in A| X_n = x_n, X_1 = x_1, ..., X_{n-k}=x_{n-k})P(X_n = x_n| X_1 = x_1, ..., X_{n-k}=x_{n-k})f(x_n)dx_n$$

Comment: I believe what you are trying to prove follows directly from the definition.  If the last known r.v is $X_{n-k}$ then the Markov property says the distribution of $X_{n+1}$  depends only on $X_{n-k}$ and not previous r.v.'s..

Comment: This is an exercise from a set of lecture notes, so if so then the professor is asking a void question, which I can't imagine would be the case

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Formal_definition  This might help.

Comment: This does not help.  The article re-writes the definition I put prior to my attempted proof.

Comment: I think the article goes deeper, so my original comment is implied.

Comment: The approach you are trying should work out if you use induction on k.